# Why was this regex calling substcont an excessive number of times?

Tags: regex, perl, optimization, profiling

This is more out of curiosity than anything else, as I'm failing to find any useful info on Google about this function (CORE::substcont)

In profiling and optimising some old, slow, XML parsing code I've found that the following regex is calling substcont 31 times for each time the line is executed, and taking a huge amount of time:

> Calls: 10000 Time: 2.65s Sub calls: 320000 Time in subs: 1.15s`

```
  $handle =~s/(>)\s*(<)/$1\n$2/g;
  # spent  1.09s making 310000 calls to main::CORE:substcont, avg 4µs/call
  # spent  58.8ms making  10000 calls to main::CORE:subst, avg 6µs/call
```

Compared to the immediately preceding line:

> Calls: 10000 Time: 371ms Sub calls: 30000 Time in subs: 221ms

```
  $handle =~s/(.*)\s*(<\?)/$1\n$2/g;
    # spent   136ms making 10000 calls to main::CORE:subst, avg 14µs/call
    # spent  84.6ms making 20000 calls to main::CORE:substcont, avg 4µs/call
```

The number of substcont calls is quite surprising, especially seeing as I would've thought that the second regex would be more expensive. This is, obviously, why profiling is a Good Thing ;-)

I've subsequently changed both these line to remove the unneccessary backrefs, with dramatic results for the badly-behaving line:

> Calls:10000 Time: 393ms Sub calls: 10000 Time in subs: 341ms

```
$handle =~s/>\s*</>\n</g;
  # spent   341ms making 10000 calls to main::CORE:subst, avg 34µs/call
```

- So, my question is - why should the original have been making SO many calls to substcont, and what does substcont even do in the regex engine that takes so long?

Comment: ...and I'm sure there's better ways we could be doing XML processing, but for now I'm stuck improving with what we've got incrementally :-/

Comment: Would mind posting a sample of what you're processing?

Comment: It's just SOAP (XML) payloads via HTTP POST. However, it comes with a fun mix of:

Whitespace on the start of some lines,

Mixed line ending styles,

Multiple tags on the same line,

More than one newline between tags,

'interstitial' text between some tags.

So this is just a preparatory step to split the content up into vaguely sensible lines - not really something that should be dominating the execution time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`substcont` is Perl's internal name for the "substitution iterator".  Something to do with `s///`.  Based on what little information I have, it seems `substcont` is triggered when doing a backref.  That is, when `$1` is present.  You can play with it a bit using B::Concise.

Here's the opcodes of a simple regex without a backref.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -we'$foo = "foo";  $foo =~ s/(foo)/bar/ig'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <$> const[PV "foo"] s
4  <#> gvsv[*foo] s
5  <2> sassign vKS/2
6  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
7  <#> gvsv[*foo] s
8  <$> const[PV "bar"] s
9  </> subst(/"(foo)"/) vKS
a  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

And one with.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -we'$foo = "foo";  $foo =~ s/(foo)/$1/ig'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <$> const[PV "foo"] s
4  <#> gvsv[*foo] s
5  <2> sassign vKS/2
6  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
7  <#> gvsv[*foo] s
8  </> subst(/"(foo)"/ replstart->9) vKS
9      <#> gvsv[*1] s
a      <|> substcont(other->8) sK/1
b  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

That's all I can offer.  You may want to try [Rx](http://perl.plover.com/Rx/), mjd's old regex debugger.